# How do I fix my CSS issue?

Tags: html, css, containers

I'm simply trying to keep the body color from spilling inside the middle of my page (between the 2 sidebars), which I want to keep white.

I'm kind of building this template from scratch and really want to do it the right way so that I can use it for other html projects as well.  Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and what I could do better to make the css work?

Thanks!

URL [here](http://www.cheapottoman.info)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put this style for your container:

```
#container { 
   margin:0 auto; 
   width:900px;  
   background:white 
}
```

This is because by default background value for HTML element is transparent, so everything is see-through unless you specify otherwise

Comment: Thank you!  I thought for sure I had tried that, but I guess I had put in background-color.  I'm glad it was easy.
Many many thanks!

I was also wondering.. if I decided I wanted to use a background image, is there a size that works best?

Comment: What you can do is have a container that resizes:

`<div style='position:absolute;z-index:0;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%'>
  <img src='whatever.jpg' style='width:100%;height:100%' alt='[]' />
</div>`
This way, the div will sit behind the page and take up the whole space, while resizing as needed. The img inside will automatically resize to fit the div.